# Importing dates to excel, conversion fails. Language/regional settings probably the reason

Tags: excel, date-formatting, regional-settings, csv-import

So I use the get external data from text function in Excel.

The file I am importing is [this one](http://epguides.com/common/exportToCSV.asp?rage=3918).

I just paste the url in the open file dialog, that works just OK. Then I go through the importing-wizard and all is OK. I press finish, and excel imports the data.

The problem is with the date-columns:

```
.....,   26/Sep/05,  ...

.....,   03/Oct/05,  ....
```

The results I do get in my excel-file is:

`26.09.2005`  => correctly converted to Norwegian format

`03/Oct/05`   => no conversion done at all

They do not convert to correct dates in my excel file. I have chosen `DMY` in the import-wizard. But it seems my computer, which has regional settings set to Norwegian, doesn't recognize "Oct" as short for October, or the 10th month.

In Norwegian October is "oktober", and shortened it is "okt" instead of "oct". The import works fine for the dates with a month that has the same short form as in Norwegian. That is jan,feb,mar,apr,jun,jul, aug, sep and nov.

For months October December and may I have this problem. From English to Norwegian the shortened versions are may=>mai, oct=>okt and dec=>des

Is there a way to tell excel that "when you see 'Oct', just think of it as 'Okt' and do your thing"?

Answer (score 0):

You can change language for office applications by using [language tool in Microsoft Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-the-default-language-setting-HP003088462.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. If I could apply the change to only the workbooks I chose myself I would do it. But in most cases I am happy with using norwegian.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set anything during the import, but there's nothing stopping you doing a `find and replace` once the data is imported.

Find `/Oct/` and replace with `/Okt/`. You should find Excel immediately recognises the updated cells are now in date format. Wouldn't be hard to do a macro that makes doing the find and replace for each month a quick job.

Of course, you can just change your regional settings temporarily if you like.

Comment: Yes, that worked. I recorded a macro that changed /Oct/ to /Okt/, and the cells also, after macro did its job, automatically changed into the date format I had selected for the cells. Thank you!